# iOS SKProductsRequest returning 0 products intermittently

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've got an iPhone app that has been live for some time now. Mostly, in app purchases work great, but for some users (< 1%), SKProductsRequest is returning 0 products (should be 1).

Does anyone have any insights into why this might be happening? I am stumped as to how to reproduce the problem locally. Things I've ruled out are:

- No net connection at request time
- Parental controls on in app purchases
- Jailbreaking (vanilla jailbreaking with no tweaks causes no problems)

I don't know if there are any invalid identifiers returned, but I'm not sure this info would help much.

One thing I have been unable to rule out is whether this is only happening for certain stores (countries) but not others. I won't have data on this until my next release goes live.

Any suggestions? I am at my wits end. Thanks in advance!

Note: There are a lot of questions on S.O. about SKProductsRequest returning 0 products, but these all seem to be about problems while testing SKProductsRequest pre-release, and not after a successful deployment where failure is intermittent.

Comment: we are also experiencing this issue. Our app has been live for months and suddenly responses are empty intermittently. Has your issue been resolved?

Comment: Any ideas? We are experiencing the same issue...